# How to capture line number within existing code in C/C++?

Tags: c++, line

I'm trying to perform some analysis of an existing program and need to log line numbers without modifying the program too much. I've been playing with `__LINE__` and was hoping to do something like this:

**file.h:**

```
void Function( int iLine = __LINE___ );   // original function had no arguments, but now overloaded to default __LINE__
```

**file.cpp:**

```
void Function( int iLine ) {    // original function had no arguments, but now changed to int iLine
    // do something here
    // log iLine number to a file for analysis
}
```

**main.cpp** call:

```
Function();    // call existing function
```

However, I now know this is not going to work as `iLine` is always the `file.h` definition line number.

I've tried StackWalker, but also had difficulty and seemed a little overkill.

Any suggestions on how to approach this while keeping original file changes minimal?

Comment: Do not tag C when asking C++ questions that do not have any particular C component. There was also no reason for the stack tag.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Use a function like macro instead of a function. The macro will expand into the "call" site, thus giving the correct line. The macro itself may be as simple as passing the argument into a proper function.

Option 2: Use `std::source_location` instead, which will be introduced in the upcoming c++20.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how the `ASSERT()` macro is defined.

If I remember well, it is something like this:

```
#define ASSERT(x) _assert( (x), __FILE__, __LINE__ );
void _assert( bool expression, const char* pfile, int line );
```

So, the `ASSERT()` macro is used as a wrapper for the `_assert()` function, so it is expanded at the call site, and it is irrelevant whether the target function gets inlined or not.

Comment: This use of _assert seems not working on my computer. Nevertheless, with the macro NDEBUG undefined, it works for me with : 
#include <assert.h>
#define ASSERT(x) assert( (x), \_\_FILE\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_ ); 
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert for more details.